# Magento share carts between all users

Tags: magento, cart

I recently set up a Mangento but I have issue with the cart.
In fact, if one user add a product to his cart it will add it to all users cart and some people will have products in their cart that they never had...

Someone already have this issue ?
I'm looking for solutions since days and I found nothing

Thanks

Comment: How about showing your code so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by going into Root Directory / var and remove the session folder. This maybe a session or persistent shopping issue. Is this a stock install, any custom themes?